# At Stack Overflow careers, header saying remaining invitations is a bit confusing

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I see Profile Invitations: 7 / 9 remaining above my profile in SOC, but although it is OK (a ratio), it sounds like it says you have 7 profile invitations, with side comment that 9 are remaining (more than you were awarded)

maybe write instead:

Profile Invitations: 7 remaining (out of 9 awarded)

Comment: Careers [is being closed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/312572/447356) - this request is no longer relevant.

Comment: since it is going to be replicated into Jobs tab, I guess it is still relevant

Comment: Might be, though still can't really see how it will work as a tab on SO.

Comment: hope they don't force one to set up their profile again...

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will all be imported, that side is most likely covered.

Comment: indeed, I see a Jobs tab now (marked as beta) and at the "edit cv" page there is all the stuff I had added to careers, plus they give you a public cv URL (don't remember if they were giving such before). http://stackoverflow.com/cv/birbilis

Answer (score 2):

7/9 actually reads as `7 of 9`

So, this: `7 / 9 remaining above my profile in SOC` would read as:

> 7 of 9 remaining invitations

which is both simple and clear. I don't see a reason why it needs to be re-written as:  `Profile Invitations: 7 remaining (out of 9 awarded)`

Comment: 7 remaining out of 9

would be better in my opinion if you don't want to use lots of words, but anything is better than the /